# How can I play sound file (mp3,wav,etc) directly with no associated application?

Tags: delphi, winapi, audio

I need also to be able to control its volume.
Also, how do I control system sound volume, to detect low volume, or mute states ?

Answer (score 2):

Use Shoban's link for how to play sound.

Here's how to control the sound volume for devices:

```
uses MMSystem;

type
   TVolumeRec = record
     case Integer of
       0: (LongVolume: Longint) ;
       1: (LeftVolume, RightVolume : Word) ;
     end;

const DeviceIndex=5
       {0:Wave
        1:MIDI
        2:CDAudio
        3:Line-In
        4:Microphone
        5:Master
        6:PC-loudspeaker}

procedure SetVolume(aVolume:Byte) ;
var 
  Vol: TVolumeRec;
begin
   Vol.LeftVolume := aVolume shl 8;
   Vol.RightVolume:= Vol.LeftVolume;
   auxSetVolume(UINT(DeviceIndex), Vol.LongVolume) ;
end;

function GetVolume:Cardinal;
var 
  Vol: TVolumeRec;
begin
   AuxGetVolume(UINT(DeviceIndex),@Vol.LongVolume) ;
   Result:=(Vol.LeftVolume + Vol.RightVolume) shr 9;
end;
```

Answer (score 2):

If this is for non-commercial use, the [BASS](http://www.un4seen.com/) libraries are free and give you the control you're looking for.

There are free video tutorials on [3DBuzz](http://www.3dbuzz.com), one of which is creating your own MP3 player.  They're in the Video Category list on the front page.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this article: [Your first MP3 Delphi player](http://delphi.about.com/od/multimedia/l/aa112800a.htm).  It uses TMediaPlayer to be able to play mp3 files.  Not exactly what you want, but a very good starting point.

Answer (score 0):

Just use MM apis (tons of samples on MSDN and google)

Answer (score -3):

```
char *mp3FilePath    = ...   ;
char *workingDirPath = ...   ;
ShellExecute(hwnd, "open", mp3FilePath, NULL, workingDirPath, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
```